# Clarification on Conv2D() syntax in keras

Tags: python, keras

This is a line of code taken from the CIFAR-10 CNN example on the keras website.
https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/

The dataset consists of

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
```

What does the 32 after the `(` mean and what is the default stride length?

Comment: Answers are in the very same documentation. Default stride length is 1, 32 is the dimensionality of the output, so the number of feature maps generated.

Comment: @AdamTL why do I need to specify the size of the output when the padding technically does that for me? If the padding is “same” then the output should have the same dimensionality as the input.

Comment: It's not size of the output image - it's the number of different convolution filters that will be used to extract features from the data. So you'll get 32 maps of features, each the size of your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for keras `conv2d` :

```
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

`32` after `(` means the number of filters. In this context filter is same as kernel, feature map. You can think of each filter as storing a single template/pattern. You are basically trying to find out the similarity between the stored template and different locations in the input.

Default `stride` is 1. It means how many pixels do you want to move altogether.

Here is a great illustration from [Stanford's deep learning tutorial](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/).

Comment: So after applying the padding, the model will add the sum of 32 different filters upon one section of the image, where that given sum will become the "value" of that one section of the original image. 

How are the values within each individual filter out of the 32 determined? is it randomized or does the conv layer determine the most effective one?

Comment: That is what CNN tries to optimise. It is the value of the filters. They are initialised with random vectors or gaussian distribution. You can check this great [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/200546)